# Javascript json customization

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Hi here i am trying to manipulate one json file to below format. I am not able to think how to do that ?

The way i am thinking is not efficient thats why i need hep on this ?

Is there any easy way to do this.

Please have a look

```
[
 {
    "nid": "61629",
    "title": "K02 - Kiosk Slider - EN",
    "itemsSlider": [
      {
        "nid": "61626",
        "status": "1",
        "titleNode": "01Additional Suitcase - EN",
        "language": "en_US"
      },
      {
        "nid": "61626",
        "status": "1",
        "titleNode": "01Additional Suitcase - EN",
        "language": "en_US"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "nid": "61629",
    "title": "K02 - Kiosk Slider - EN",
    "itemsSlider": [
      {
        "nid": "61626",
        "status": "1",
        "titleNode": "01Additional Suitcase - EN",
        "language": "es_MX"
      },
      {
        "nid": "61626",
        "status": "1",
        "titleNode": "01Additional Suitcase - EN",
        "language": "es_MX"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "nid": "61629",
    "title": "K02 - Kiosk Slider - EN",
    "itemsSlider": [
      {
        "nid": "61626",
        "status": "1",
        "titleNode": "01Additional Suitcase - EN",
        "language": "fr_FR"
      },
      {
        "nid": "61626",
        "status": "1",
        "titleNode": "01Additional Suitcase - EN",
        "language": "fr_FR"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "nid": "61629",
    "title": "K02 - Kiosk Slider - Mix",
    "itemsSlider": [
      {
        "nid": "61626",
        "status": "1",
        "titleNode": "01Additional Suitcase - EN",
        "language": "es_MX"
      },
      {
        "nid": "61626",
        "status": "1",
        "titleNode": "01Additional Suitcase - EN",
        "language": "en_US"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

THis this the output i am expecting for:
Please have a look Is there any way to achive it?

```
{
  "es_MX": [
    {
      "nid": "61626",
      "status": "1",
      "titleNode": "01Additional Suitcase - EN",
      "language": "es_MX"
    },
    {
      "nid": "61626",
      "status": "1",
      "titleNode": "01Additional Suitcase - EN",
      "language": "es_MX"
    }
  ],
  "fr_FR": [
    {
      "nid": "61626",
      "status": "1",
      "titleNode": "01Additional Suitcase - EN",
      "language": "fr_FR"
    },
    {
      "nid": "61626",
      "status": "1",
      "titleNode": "01Additional Suitcase - EN",
      "language": "fr_FR"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `i am trying to manipulate` - did you forget to show how you're *trying* to do this?

Comment: You also need to explain why language en_US has disappeared - and why things are duplicated as they are - and why is `K02 - Kiosk Slider - Mix` ignored too

Comment: I am trying to manipulate [link](https://onecompiler.com/javascript/42786nfuf)

Comment: what is the problem? your code works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For check duplicate, you can use `includes` in javascript, Like this

```js
let source = [{
    "nid": "61629",
    "title": "K02 - Kiosk Slider - EN",
    "itemsSlider": [
      {
        "nid": "61626",
        "status": "1",
        "titleNode": "01Additional Suitcase - EN",
        "language": "en_US"
      },
      {
        "nid": "61626",
        "status": "1",
        "titleNode": "01Additional Suitcase - EN",
        "language": "en_US"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "nid": "61629",
    "title": "K02 - Kiosk Slider - EN",
    "itemsSlider": [
      {
        "nid": "61626",
        "status": "1",
        "titleNode": "01Additional Suitcase - EN",
        "language": "es_MX"
      },
      {
        "nid": "61626",
        "status": "1",
        "titleNode": "01Additional Suitcase - EN",
        "language": "es_MX"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "nid": "61629",
    "title": "K02 - Kiosk Slider - EN",
    "itemsSlider": [
      {
        "nid": "61626",
        "status": "1",
        "titleNode": "01Additional Suitcase - EN",
        "language": "fr_FR"
      },
      {
        "nid": "61626",
        "status": "1",
        "titleNode": "01Additional Suitcase - EN",
        "language": "fr_FR"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "nid": "61629",
    "title": "K02 - Kiosk Slider - Mix",
    "itemsSlider": [
      {
        "nid": "61626",
        "status": "1",
        "titleNode": "01Additional Suitcase - EN",
        "language": "es_MX"
      },
      {
        "nid": "61626",
        "status": "1",
        "titleNode": "01Additional Suitcase - EN",
        "language": "en_US"
      }
    ]
  }]
let result = {};
    let duplicates = {};

    for (let item of source) {
      for (let subItem of item.itemsSlider) {
        if (!result[subItem.language]) {
          result[subItem.language] = [];
        }
        if (!duplicates[subItem.language]) {
          duplicates[subItem.language] = [];
        }
        if (!duplicates[subItem.language].includes(subItem.nid)) {
          duplicates[subItem.language].push(subItem.nid);
          result[subItem.language].push(subItem);
        }
      }
    }
    
    console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
let source = [ /* your source JSON */ ];
let result = {};

for (let item of source) {
    for (let subItem of item.itemsSlider) {
        if (!result[subItem.language]) {
            result[subItem.language] = [];
        }
        result[subItem.language].push(subItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, in this solution what would you add so that items are not duplicated?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Array::reduce()`:

```js
const result = data.reduce((r, {itemsSlider}) => (itemsSlider.forEach(item => (r[item.language]??=[]).push(item)), r), {});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script>
const data = [
 {
    "nid": "61629",
    "title": "K02 - Kiosk Slider - EN",
    "itemsSlider": [
      {
        "nid": "61626",
        "status": "1",
        "titleNode": "01Additional Suitcase - EN",
        "language": "en_US"
      },
      {
        "nid": "61626",
        "status": "1",
        "titleNode": "01Additional Suitcase - EN",
        "language": "en_US"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "nid": "61629",
    "title": "K02 - Kiosk Slider - EN",
    "itemsSlider": [
      {
        "nid": "61626",
        "status": "1",
        "titleNode": "01Additional Suitcase - EN",
        "language": "es_MX"
      },
      {
        "nid": "61626",
        "status": "1",
        "titleNode": "01Additional Suitcase - EN",
        "language": "es_MX"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "nid": "61629",
    "title": "K02 - Kiosk Slider - EN",
    "itemsSlider": [
      {
        "nid": "61626",
        "status": "1",
        "titleNode": "01Additional Suitcase - EN",
        "language": "fr_FR"
      },
      {
        "nid": "61626",
        "status": "1",
        "titleNode": "01Additional Suitcase - EN",
        "language": "fr_FR"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "nid": "61629",
    "title": "K02 - Kiosk Slider - Mix",
    "itemsSlider": [
      {
        "nid": "61626",
        "status": "1",
        "titleNode": "01Additional Suitcase - EN",
        "language": "es_MX"
      },
      {
        "nid": "61626",
        "status": "1",
        "titleNode": "01Additional Suitcase - EN",
        "language": "en_US"
      }
    ]
  }
]
</script>
```